# How to set C# language version for miscellaneous files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Is there a way to instruct Visual Studio to use C# 7.1 or greater for Intellisense analysis of miscellaneous (non-project) files?**

Visual Studio 2017 allows you to specify the C# language version to use for compiling source files using a new project file property (see [Language version selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#language-version-selection)). I have successfully used this to compile a project using some features of C# 7.1.

However, this setting seems to be ignored when viewing C# files from *outside* the current solution, which happens when debugging into an external library.

Assuming you have both the source code and appropriate symbol files, Visual Studio supports debugging into external libraries. When these files are opened, they appear as "Miscellaneous Files", not associated with any specific project in the solution. I find however when I open one of these files that makes use of C# 7.1 language features, I get the Intellisense error `CS8107: Feature 'default literal' is not available in C#7. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.` C# 7.1 *is* enabled in the currently loaded project.

This is turn prevents me from setting any breakpoints in the file.